# How to get a large number of Westend (Polkadot Testnet) tokens

Tags: faucet

Which faucet can provide a large number of Westend tokens (WND)? I want to stake on Westend, but I cannot do it right away as I can only get 1 WND every day at https://app.element.io/#/room/#westend_faucet:matrix.org,

Comment: What do you need more for? Typically there is ability for more to be granted from those that maintains the faucet if you have an appropriate and reasonable need for them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no faucet that gives away a large amount of Westend tokens.

If you need Westend tokens beyond what the faucet provides, you should reach out to the development team with clarification of how much you need and why.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/community